# Having trouble permutting 2 lines in my 2d array [C++]

Tags: c++

Hey so I have this is assignement in class where I need to create a 2D array using pointers (I need to use pointers even tho it's not the best way) and once it's create have a fucntion switch 2 lines. So here's where i'm stuck it keeps crashing on me. I had it that it changed colons but now lines because I made a mistake in my func permutter() because I had put pt1 and pt2 where 'i' is now but since I changed that it crash and I can't seem to find why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

void creationMat(double **,int,int);
void afficher(double **,int,int);
void permutter(double **,int,int,int);

int main(){
    int l;
    int c;
    bool invalide = true;
    do {
        cout << "Veuiller entrer le nombre de ligne  et de colonne  pour la 
           matrice : "<<endl; //"Pleas enter the number of lines and colonne
        cin >> l >> c;
        if (cin.fail() || l<=0 || c<=0 ){
            cerr << "Le nombre entrer est invalide!"<<endl;
            cin.clear();
        }
        else{
            invalide = false;
        }
        while(cin.get() != '\n'); // vidange du tampon      
    }while(invalide);           
    // réservation sur le tas
    double **mat;
    mat = new double*[l];
    for(int i = 0; i<l; i++)
        mat[i] = new double[c];

    creationMat(mat,l,c);
    afficher(mat,l,c);
    int pt1, pt2;
    cout << "Veuiller entrer les deux lignes a permutter (entre 0 et " << l-
         1 << ") : " <<endl;
    cin >>pt1>>pt2;
    permutter(mat,l,pt1,pt2);
    afficher(mat,l,c);
}


void creationMat(double **mat, int l, int c){
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i=0; i<l; ++i){
        for(int j=0; j<c; ++j){
            int num = rand()%9+1;
            *(*(mat+i)+j) = num;
        }
    }
}

void afficher(double **mat, int l, int c){
    for (int i=0; i<l; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<c; j++){
            cout << mat[i][j] << " || ";
        }
        cout<<endl;     
    }
}

void permutter(double **mat,int l, int pt1, int pt2){
    double *temp = new double[l];
    for (int i=0; i<l; i++){
        *(temp+i) = *(*(mat+pt1)+i);
        *(*(mat+pt1)+i) = *(*(mat+pt2)+i);
        *(*(mat+pt2)+i) = *(temp+i);        
    } 

}
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Well that's weird I didn't change anything and it's working now 0.o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't crash it, but you are calling `permutter` with invalid argument(should be `c` instead of `l`). This way your swapped values are going to mix with values from other lines if `c != l`. Also you don't need to allocated array in `permutter` because you are using at most one temporary element at a time(and you should `delete` that allocation as right now you're leaking memory).

Anyway, as you're using array of pointers, you can optimize your code and just swap pointers instead of rewriting content of arrays.